# Trying to recode raster with CSV using the Grass r.recode.attr but getting error "name 'xrange' is not defined"

Tags: qgis, raster, grass-gis

I'm trying to recode a large GSSURGO soil raster with CSV using the Grass [r.recode.attr](https://grass.osgeo.org/grass7/manuals/addons/r.recode.attr.html) following these instructions https://pvanb.wordpress.com/2014/12/13/recode-your-raster-file-in-grass-gis-using-a-csv-file/ but I'm getting error **"name 'xrange' is not defined"**

When I looked it up I found that this issue may be because "xrange" changed to "range" in the transition from from Python 2 to Python 3. The instructions for the r.recode.attr module are from 2014 and I can't find much else out there the talks about r.recode.attr. However, it seems like a very valuable tool.

My raster, instead of being classed by values has a unique key which only has meaning if you can reclassify it from a related CSV table. Does anyone know of any alternative using GRASS or QGIS?

Comment: Yes, the 2to3 update tool of Python suggest to replace "xrange()" with "range()" (in line 88) - can you try that?

Comment: ok meanwhile I have submitted a fix as https://github.com/OSGeo/grass-addons/pull/91 (yet to be accepted)

Answer (score 0):

Please update your installation of the GRASS GIS addon r.recode.attr to the latest version. I have updated it to be Python 3 compliant (https://github.com/OSGeo/grass-addons/pull/91 - xrange compatibility fix).

The addon now works.